# Método get do http sendo invocado automaticamente

Tags: java-ee, jsp, servlet, servlet-3

Bom dia pessoal, estou implementando o método get um servlet aqui com uma lógica muito simples.

Caso o usuário passe uma url no padrão: ".../entidades/id", deverá ser aberto o formulário de edição já com a entidade correspondente à id digitada após a barra. Porém se o padrão da url for: ".../entidades" será carregada a lista de todas as entidades e aberta a página de listagem de entidades.

Já está tudo funcionando, porém com um problema. Após a execução da última linha está voltado para o início do método get, como se algo estivesse reinvocando o método get, então fica em loop infinito.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String requestUri = req.getRequestURI();
    Long id = RegexUtil.matchId(requestUri);

    if (id != null) {
        // Informou um id
        Entidade entidade = entidadeService.getEntidadeById(id);

        if (entidade != null) {

            req.setAttribute("objEntidade", entidade);                
            req.getRequestDispatcher("paginas/cadastroentidades.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            // Após executar esta linha, volta automaticamente para a primeira linha do método
        } else {
            resp.sendError(404, "Entidade não encontrada");
        }

    } else {

        List<Entidade> lstEntidades = entidadeService.getEntidades();

        req.setAttribute("lstEntidades", lstEntidades);            
        req.getRequestDispatcher("paginas/listaentidades.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        // Após executar esta linha, volta automaticamente para a primeira linha do método
    }
}
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, minha suspeita é que você utilizando o caminho relativo esta sendo redirecionado para a mesma servlet, tente usar o caminho absoluto para essa sua pagina jsp, segue um exemplo:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/paginas/listaentidades.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Comment: Olá Leonardo Villela, obrigado pela dica, vou testar hoje a noite e posto aqui se for resolvido.

Comment: Olá de nada, se ajudar não esqueça de marcar a pergunta como respodida e avalidar a resposta, bons estudos :)

Comment: Valeu, Leonardo Villela, resolvi aqui seguindo sua dica.